# NEST C# Get part of text where word/phrase appears

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Elasticsearch with NEST C# and I was wondering if is it possible to get a part of text where the searched word or phrase appears.

For example: If we have this text in a field of a document:

"William Shakespeare was an English poet, playwright, and actor. He was born on 26 April 1564 in Stratford-upon-Avon. His father was a successful local businessman and his mother was the daughter of a landowner. Shakespeare is widely regarded as the greatest writer in the English language and the world's pre-eminent dramatist. He is often called England's national poet and nicknamed the Bard of Avon. He wrote about 38 plays, 154 sonnets, two long narrative poems, and a few other verses, of which the authorship of some is uncertain. His plays have been translated into every major living language and are performed more often than those of any other playwright."

And I search "**Bard of Avon**". Is there any way to get the part of the full text with my word or phrase appears and the surrounding words? Something like: 
"...called England's national poet and nicknamed the **Bard of Avon**. He wrote about 38 plays, 154 sonnets ..."

When I search:

```
var result = client.Search<Books>(b => b
        .Size(100)
        .Query(
           query => query.Match(
               s => s.
                   Field(p => p.ContainedText).Query("Bard of Avon"))));
```

Now, I save the first document, for example and I can access to all the fields that this document have.

```
var doc =  res.Documents.First();
```

I have now the doc.ContainedText that have all text (Shakespeare Paragraph).
But I don't see an option for get just a part or parts of them, where the word appears. Is it possible?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, please show us code that you have already tried to solve this issue and let us know why it isn't working.

Comment: @César Take a look at highlighting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: @RussCam I have read this, but that's not what I want. I only want to do the same as Google. When you search a phrase it show results with a part of text where your word or phrase appears.

Comment: @César that's exactly what highlighting is; search for a word or phrase and highlight in the `_source` where that word or phrase appears. In your application, you can truncate the `_source` to show only a portion around each highlighted hit.

Comment: @RussCam Ok, then I will try! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

yes possible. try this

```
string mytext = "William Shakespeare was an English poet, playwright, and actor. He was born on 26 April 1564 in Stratford-upon-Avon. His father was a successful local businessman and his mother was the daughter of a landowner. Shakespeare is widely regarded as the greatest writer in the English language and the world's pre-eminent dramatist. He is often called England's national poet and nicknamed the Bard of Avon. He wrote about 38 plays, 154 sonnets, two long narrative poems, and a few other verses, of which the authorship of some is uncertain. His plays have been translated into every major living language and are performed more often than those of any other playwright.";
            string tofind = "Bard of Avon";
            string resltantSentence = "";
            if (mytext.Contains(tofind))
            {
                // suppose tofind is InStart / In Middle /In the End of a sentence.
                // and we want the whole sentence out.
                //so first split all sentences in arrays
                string[] sentences = mytext.Split(". ");
                foreach (string sentence in sentences)
                {
                    //and find the string in each sentence,
                    // if the string is repeated in multiple sentences, then you can have array of "resltantSentence" instead and comment the break statement.
                    if (sentence.Contains(tofind))
                    {
                        resltantSentence = sentence;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's a way to do it at C# code. But my question is if NEST has a method or something like this that get the result that I am looking for.